# Hi, I am developing an mobile application using flutter and I am bit confused if the strategy I am following is correct?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I created a separate Stateless widget called CustomAppBar will certain parameters.
Every I need appBar in my app. I will use CustomAppBar and give required parameters instead of normal AppBar.

like this :

```
 appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: CustomAppBar(title: 'Wishlist', enableBack: widget.enableBack),
      ),
```

I would like to know, if this is correct way or will it have any impact on performance and app crashes.

Any help is really appreciated. Thankyou.

Please check the code below (CustomAppBar):

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  bool enableBack;
  String title;
  Color backgroundColor;
  bool enableSearchBar;
  bool showLogo;
  bool isSearchPage;

  CustomAppBar(
      {Key key,
      this.enableBack = true,
      this.title,
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
      this.enableSearchBar = false,
      this.showLogo = false,
      this.isSearchPage = false})
      : super(key: key);

  // const CustomAppBar({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        leading: enableBack
            ? GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 18,
                ),
              )
            : const SizedBox(),
        centerTitle: enableBack ? false : true,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff004aad),
        titleSpacing: 0,
        leadingWidth: 50,
        title: showLogo
            ? Row(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                    child: Image(
                      height: 35,
                      width: 35,
                      // width: 400,
                      image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/featured_images/logo-transparent.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  CustomSizedTextBox(
                    textContent: "TITLE",
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontName: 'Alegreya Sans',
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : Text(
                title,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
              ),
        actions: enableSearchBar
            ? [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        isSearchPage
                            ? Navigator.pop(context)
                            : Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/search');
                      },
                      child: const Icon(
                        CupertinoIcons.search,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/wishlist');
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.heart,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/cart',
                          arguments: Cart(
                            enableBack: true,
                          ));
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.bag,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            : []);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach, there's nothing wrong with that.

Another approach commonly used to implement a custom app bar is by implement `PreferredSizeWidget` in your `CustomAppBar`:

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  bool enableBack;
  String title;
  Color backgroundColor;
  bool enableSearchBar;
  bool showLogo;
  bool isSearchPage;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(50);

  CustomAppBar(
      {Key key,
      this.enableBack = true,
      this.title,
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
      this.enableSearchBar = false,
      this.showLogo = false,
      this.isSearchPage = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now you can use your `CustomAppBar` like the original `AppBar`:

```dart
appBar: CustomAppBar(title: 'Wishlist', enableBack: widget.enableBack),
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me out. Can I assume your answer as, the approach is correct and will not have any impact on performance.

Comment: You're right, performance issues are not caused by a simple widget configuration like that